# mount.ntfs taking all the CPU (WUBI)

Tags: wubi, performance, ntfs, cpu

I installed yesterday Ubuntu following the 'click and play' instructions of the (nicely done) ubuntu website. I used WUBI. Its installed in a partition of a drive that mainly has a Windows 7 install.

After several problems I realized mount.ntfs was often taking above 90% of the CPU which caused the system to hang / become unresponsive etc.

I did some research and I saw that the ntfs-3g driver has some bugs. I also read that WUBI was not a good medium to install ubuntu.

My questions are:

1) if wubi is not reliable why is it promoted so heavily on the website?
2) Would installing another distribution or even FreeBSD work better?
3) Would installing Ubuntu on an external drive of the file system type that Linux works with solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding wubi itself is not a problem, and installation is not a problem, reason behind the wubi to under perform is that when you had windows and started installing ubuntu from windows, you will store it on ntfs drive which is windows file system where ubuntu has different type of filesystem, so converting the file system form ntfs to ext4 filesystem takes processing power therefore mount.ntfs takes up that CPU power. if you had installed ubuntu normally you would not have mount.ntfs at all and normal system behavior.  wubi was designed for people that want to start experimenting ubuntu while keeping windows OS data untouched.

1. wubi is reliable when you think of it, it did its job, it installed
   ubuntu with windows and  configured grup so that you choose between
   OS, and note that wubi will be discontinued in future releases.
2. installing another Linux system you would need to delete
   partition/shrink partition  from windows then install the linux
   distribution on it.
3. installing it on external drive would make it slower, reason is the
   i/o r/w operations will go trough USB/Network which is slower.

That said, its up to you to choose what you need best.